# Add AndroidSlidingUpPanel to IntelliJ IDEA project using Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I create a project on IntelliJ IDEA using Gradle and I'm trying to add AndroidSlidingUpPanel to it (https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel).

What exactly do I have to do to configure it?

I have the following folder structure:

```
RootFolder
|_libraries
    |_ AndroidSlidingUpPanel
         |_ library
               |_ build.gradle
         |_ settings.gradle
         |_ build.gradle
|_app
    |_ build.gradle
|_ settings.gradle
|_ build.gradle
```

The files are like this:

RootFolder/settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:AndroidSlidingUpPanel:library'
```

RootFolder/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

RootFolder/libraries/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/settings.gradle

```
include ':library'
include ':demo'
```

RootFolder/libraries/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/build.gradle

```
allprojects {

  group 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel'
  version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

  buildscript {
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
    }
  }

  dependencies {
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
    }
  }
}
```

RootFolder/libraries/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/library/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

RootFolder/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't clear about what build errors you may be having or what your exact question is, though since you haven't got a dependency to SlidingUpPanel in your **app/build.gradle**, the question is how to include it?

If so, the first thing to bear in mind is that a project can't have more than one **settings.gradle**. To be more precise, it only looks in the root folder for it and uses it if it's there. So the **settings.gradle** in **RootFolder/libraries/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/** will be ignored. It looks like you've properly set up an `include` to the SlidingUpPanel library in **RootFolder/settings.gradle**, so that's good:

```
include ':libraries:AndroidSlidingUpPanel:library'
```

to include a dependency on it in your app, you use a `compile project` statement and give it the same path:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    compile project(':libraries:AndroidSlidingUpPanel:library')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

If you're using Android Studio (it should also work with Gradle-based projects in IntelliJ Community Edition), you can set up dependencies on modules from the Project Structure dialog via **Modules** > ***Your module*** > **Dependencies** > **+** > **Module dependency**:

[image: Project Structure dialog showing how to add a module dependency]

If you've added the module to your **settings.gradle** file as you already have and have synced up your project to the Gradle files, then the SlidingUpPanel module should appear in the Project view in the IDE and should appear as a module choice in that dependency list.